# Xamarin: Using Native library

Tags: binding, native, xamarin

1) In case of availability of iOS and Android Native libraries, what will be the appropriate, efficient and easier step to take, in order to use the library for the development of a cross platform application? Binding Android library or the iOS? If we bind the Android native library, will we be able to use this binded library in the Xamarin.iOS application and vice versa?

2) In case of availability of a a C++ library, is it possible to use this library to develop a cross platform application?

Thanks in advance!

(Just a beginner in Xamarin, so excuses if the question seems to be inappropriate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Native iOS and Android libraries are usually quite different (iOS libraries are commonly written in Objective-C and Android libraries in Java), and because of this the bindings for each will differ. Even if the API was identical, the difference between Objective-C and Java is enough for the bindings to have to be different too.
2. Yes, it is possible to use C++ in iOS and Android projects, but the mechanism is different. There are a couple of options here:

   - Use a tool such as [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) to create managed bindings for the C++ library. [This](http://blog.reblochon.org/2013/01/c-bindings-for-monotouch-using-swig.html) is also an interesting read.
   - Create a C library which wraps the C++ library, and then use the standard P/Invoke mechanism available in managed code to interact with the C library.

Comment: Thanks! The library i'm using contains no platform specific codes and is used only to connect a device to a remote server. This library is available on Objectve-C, Java and C++. I need a binding to it to access as C# class library. So, if i bind any one of these libraries, will i be able to use across different Xamarin Projects? For example: If i bind the available java library to C#, can i also use this binded library in my Xamarin.iOS project?

Comment: No, you will not be able to use the Java bindings (nor the Java library itself) on iOS, since Java only runs on Android. You should however be able to use the C++ version on both iOS and Android (and the managed binding would be sharable too in this case).

Comment: So, now i decide to use the C++ version of the library on my cross platform application. Thanks a lot.